# Сложные условия XML jasperreports

Tags: xml, jasperreports

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный синтаксис условия в XML jasperreports.

Есть условие:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{COLUMN_31}=="1"&&$F{COLUMN_32}!="1"?"Мы, ":"Я, ")]]>
     </textFieldExpression>
```

Нужно добавить в это условие: при `$F{COLUMN_31}!="1"` и `F{COLUMN_32}!="1"` выводить `" "`.